# Angular npm start it is generating browser application bundles although the app is not in production

Tags: angular, node-modules, package.json

I am dealing with an unexpected change at the npm start which it makes the server of Angular very slow.
During `npm start` it is coming Generating browser applciation bundles (phase: building)... and it is taking to much time

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-cropperjs": "^1.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.9",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.14",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.28.0",
    "ngx-awesome-uploader": "^9.0.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-gravatar": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.1.8",
    "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
    "quill-mention": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.0 <4.1"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 7.3.1.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/username/career.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/career/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/username/career#readme"
}
```

And this is my `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-project-ng": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "jwt-decode"
           ],
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/my-project-ng",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css",
              "./node_modules/quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-project-ng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-project-ng:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-project-ng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",

            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-project-ng-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-project-ng:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-project-ng:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-project-ng",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

And then it is adding some weird warnings.

```
node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on '@babel/runtime-corejs3/regenerator'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

I tried as the `Angular` page it says https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
but it didnt help, I do see the messages again.

And the time duration of the npm `npm start` & `ng serve` it is more than 1 minute.

Comment: The warning is expected if you're using CommonJS or AMD dependencies.

Comment: @mwilson I am not using none of them.

Comment: You are. It says it in the warning. Looks like you have an npm package called `canvg` that is using one.

Comment: @mwilson and what about the npm start ?

Comment: What about it? `ng start` is somewhat slow. it's definitely not instant.

Comment: @mwilson Yeah I added why, because it is creating bundles algthough it is not in production.
`Browser application bundle generation complete`

Comment: Define "creating bundles" Do you mean it's creating a dist with all the bundled modules?

Comment: @mwilson Yes it is creating a dist with all the bundled modules.

Comment: Sounds like you are running the `ng build` command. If you just run `ng start` (not `npm start`) does the dist folder regenerate?

Comment: @mwilson it is the same. it runs the `build` again

Comment: Is this issue resolved because facing exact issue. can someone help me out.

Comment: @BalarajuPolaki Nope still the same

Comment: still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've same troubles and find solutions. I can try this:
First go to node-modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/benchmark.js and change  "__esModule" from false to true, after that run ng serve --verbose --no-progress, so you will see how long it takes to load each file during the building process, my problem was with this files:

```
AngularCompilerPlugin._emit.ng.gatherDiagnostics.ng.getTsSemanticDiagnostics: 4.357s
AngularCompilerPlugin._emit.ng.gatherDiagnostics.ng.getNgSemanticDiagnostics: 43:06.434 (m:ss.mmm)
AngularCompilerPlugin._emit.ng.emit: 1.631s
AngularCompilerPlugin._emit: 43:12.435 (m:ss.mmm)
AngularCompilerPlugin._update._emit: 43:12.437 (m:ss.mmm)
AngularCompilerPlugin._update: 43:22.868 (m:ss.mmm)
AngularCompilerPlugin._make: 43:22.869 (m:ss.mmm)
ngcLoader+C:\Users\Vasil\t\src\main.ts+.ngcLoader.AngularCompilerPlugin: 0.924ms
ngcLoader+C:\Users\Vasil\t\src\main.ts+: 13.404ms
ngcLoader+C:\Users\Vasil\t\src\polyfills.ts+.ngcLoader.AngularCompilerPlugin: 17.251ms
```

After that I go to tsconfig.json and change "strictTemplates" from true to false, now works fine.
I think that the problem come after installing angular material, but not sure.

Comment: I have fixed the problem, my only problem it is that at `npm start` it start to generate bundles for production.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi can you write the answer here and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @GauravTyagi It is not solved yet.
Because still it is generating bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this. You need to add your own dev config and that will resolve the error, also it will show you the source in dev tools.

Here is the link to the answer:
['Generating browser application bundles' message while building dev version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67881011/generating-browser-application-bundles-message-while-building-dev-version/68272023#68272023)

Comment: Which solution ?
I don't see the accepted answer.

Comment: I have updated my question there is the angular.json

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/3144

Comment: I have fixed that part, only left the part of the angular.json that you said.